# TDD - Dependencies that cannot be mocked

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, tdd

Let's say I have a class:

```
class XMLSerializer {
    public function serialize($object) {
        $document = new DomDocument();
        $root = $document->createElement('object');
        $document->appendChild($root);

        foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
            $root->appendChild($document->createElement($key, $value);
        }

        return $document->saveXML();
    }

    public function unserialze($xml) {
        $document = new DomDocument();
        $document->loadXML($xml);

        $root = $document->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);

        $object = new stdclass;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $root->childNodes->length; $i++) {
            $element = $root->childNodes->item($i);
            $tagName = $element->tagName;
            $object->$tagName = $element->nodeValue();
        }

        return $object;
    }

}
```

How do I test this in isolation? When testing this class, I am also testing the DomDocument class

I could pass in the document object:

```
class XMLSerializer {
    private $document;

    public function __construct(\DomDocument $document) {
        $this->document = $document;
    }

    public function serialize($object) {
        $root = $this->document->createElement('object');
        $this->document->appendChild($root);

        foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
            $root->appendChild($this->document->createElement($key, $value);
        }

        return $this->document->saveXML();
    }

    public function unserialze($xml) {
        $this->document->loadXML($xml);

        $root = $this->document->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);

        $object = new stdclass;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $root->childNodes->length; $i++) {
            $element = $root->childNodes->item($i);
            $tagName = $element->tagName;
            $object->$tagName = $element->nodeValue();
        }

        return $object;
    }

}
```

Which seems to solve the problem, however, now my test isn't really doing anything. I need to make a mock DomDocument return the XML I'm testing in the test:

```
$object = new stdclass;
$object->foo = 'bar';

$mockDocument = $this->getMock('document')
                ->expects($this->once())
                ->method('saveXML')
                ->will(returnValue('<?xml verison="1.0"?><root><foo>bar</foo></root>'));

$serializer = new XMLSerializer($mockDocument);

$serializer->serialize($object);
```

Which has several problems:

1. I'm not actually testing the method at all, all I'm checking is that the method returns the result of `$document->saveXML()`
2. The test is aware of the implementation of the method (it uses domdocument to generate the xml)
3. The test will fail if the class is rewritten to use simplexml or another xml library, even though it could be producing the correct result

so can I test this code in isolation? It looks like I can't.. is there a name for this type of dependency that can't be mocked as its behaviour is essentially required for the method being tested?

Comment: Why do you need to test it in isolation?

Comment: Because in a real-world use case where the dependency is not inbuilt (or DomDocument) if the test fails I won't know whether the problem is with the implementation of the method I'm testing, or one of the objects it constructs. I can have separate tests for those, of course, but it's inefficient to run all the tests every time during development. As it says here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx "By isolating your code for testing, you know that if the test fails, the cause is there and not somewhere else", it just makes development/debugging faster if tests are isolated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a question regarding TDD. TDD means writing test first.

I cannot imagine starting with a test that mocks `DOMElement::createElement` before writing the actual implementation. It's natural that you start with an object and expected xml.

Also, I wouldn't call `DOMElement` a dependency. It's a private detail of your implementation. You will never pass a different implementation of `DOMElement` to the constructor of `XMLSerializer` so there's no need to expose it in the constructor.

Tests should also serve as a documentation. Simple test with an object and expected xml will be readable. Everyone will be able to read it and be sure what your class is doing. Compare this to 50 line test with mocking (PhpUnit mocks are preposterously verbose).

EDIT:
Here's a good paper about it http://www.jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf.
In a nutshell it states that unless you use tests to drive your design (find interfaces), there’s little point to using mocks.

There is also a good rule

> Only Mock Types You Own

(mentioned in the paper) that can be applied to your example.

Comment: I think this is the most sensible answer. Private implementation details should not be mocked. This does of course, have the problem of not isolating for testing but in this case the issue is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned it, test isolation is a good technique if you want to speed-up bug resolution. However, writing those test can have an important cost in terms of development as well as in terms of maintenance. **At the end of the day, what you really is want is a test suite that does not have to change each time you modify the system under test.** In other words, you write a test against an API, not against its details of implementation.

Of course, one day you may encounter a hard-to-find bug that would require test isolation in order to be spotted, but you may not need it right now. Therefore, I would suggest to test the inputs and the outputs of your system first (end-to-end test). If one day, you need more, well, you'll still be able to make some more fined grained tests.

Back to your problem, what you really want to test, is the transformation logic which is done in the serializer, no matter how it is done. Mocking a type you don't own is not an option, as making arbitrary assumptions regarding how a class interacts with its environment can lead you to problems once the code is deployed. As suggested by m1lt0n, you can encapsulate this class within a interface, and mock it for test purpose. This gives some flexibility regarding the serializer's implementation but the real question is, **do you really need that ?** **What are the benefits compared to simpler solution ?** For a first implementation, it seems to me that a simple input vs output test should be enough ("Keep it simple and stupid"). If some day you need to switch between different serializer strategy, just change the design and add some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address your questions/problems you see in the code and the tests:

> 1) I'm not actually testing the method at all, all I'm checking is that the method returns the result of $document->saveXML()

That's right, by mocking the DomDocument and it's methods return this way, you just check that the method will be called (not even that the method is returning the result of saveXML(), as I don't see an assertion for the serialize method, but just calling it, which triggers the expectation to be true).

> 2) The test is aware of the implementation of the method (it uses domdocument to generate the xml)

That's also true and very important, because if the internal implementation of the method changes, the test might fail even if it returns the proper result. The test should treat the method as a 'black box', worrying only about the return value of the method with a set of given argument(s).

> 3) The test will fail if the class is rewritten to use simplexml or another xml library, even though it could be producing the correct result

True, see my comment on (2)

So, what's the alternative then? Given your implementation of the XMLSerializer, the DomDocument just facilitates/is a helper for the actually performing the serialization. Other than that, the method just iterates over the properties of the object. So the XMLSerializer and the DomDocument are inseparable in a way and that might be just fine.

Regarding the test itself, my approach would be to provide a known object and assert that the serialize method returns an expected xml structure (since the object is known, the outcome is known, too). This way, you're not tied to the actual implementation of the method (so it does not matter if you use DomDocument or something else to actually perform the XML document creation).

Now, about the other thing you mention (injecting the DomDocument), it is of no use in the current implementation. Why? because if you want to use another tool for the creation of the XML document (simplexml etc as you mention), you'll need to change the major part of the methods. An alternative implementation is the following:

```
<?php

    interface Serializer
    {
      public function serialize($object);

      public function unserialize($xml);
    }


    class DomDocumentSerializer
    {
      public function serialize($object)
      {
     // the actual implementation, same as the sample code you provide
      }

      public function unserialize($xml)
      {
     // the actual implementation, same as the sample code you provide
      }
    }
```

The benefit from the above implementation is that whenever you need a serializer you can typehint the interface and inject any implementation, so next time you create a new SimplexmlSerializer implementation, you'll just need to go through the instantiation of the classes that need (that's where dependency injection would make sense) a serializer as an argument and just change the implementation.

Sorry for the last part and code, it may be a bit off the purpose of TDD but it will make the code that uses the serializer testable, so it's kind of relevant.